# How to get the wrongly decoded string back from sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, encode

I have lists of files, decode them and parse some strings to save to sqlite.

The problem is that one of the file is in GBK encoding while others are in UTF-8.

FileReader read those files in UTF-8, which makes the string parsed from GBK file is wrongly decoded, and the string is some strange characters like ???.

All those strings are listed in a listview, and how can i show it correctly?

I have tried new String(myString.getBytes("UTF-8"), "GBK") and new String(myString.getBytes("GBK"), "UTF-8"), but failed to get the right string.

Is it the only way that I read the file with GBK encoding again?

Answer (score 2):

As per the FileReader javadocs

> The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are appropriate. To specify these values yourself, construct an InputStreamReader on a FileInputStream.

so try

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");
```

Comment: It's true that I can read it with specidied encoding again, but I just wonder if there is a way I can recover the string without having to specify the encoding. I found the string getting from sqlite have something like "锟斤拷" which is U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.